# RHEL ISO with kickstart file

Tags: linux, kickstart

I am trying to edit the original RHEL 6.5 DVD (rhel-server-6.5-x86_64-dvd.iso) from redhat in order to add kickstart file on it. The goal is to have one 3.4Go iso with automatic install. And not one boot media and one DVD.

This technique is not supported by redhat officially, but I found a procedure : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959

My ks.cfg looks like :

```
install
cdrom
repo --name="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"  --baseurl=file:/mnt/source --cost=100
repo --name=HighAvailability --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/HighAvailability
```

I got an error when the installer start : it didn't find the disk Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

I guess this is because installer is not looking on its own media.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Does the cdrom have optional parameter to hard link the device ?

Comment: Couple of missing `/` in the base URL for the first repo. Some applications don't mind, but some may. And that link is subscriber-only.

Comment: Sorry for the link... If I found one freely available I'll share. My setup is working if I attach a second cdrom with RHEL ISO. So ks.cfg seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the repo URLs in  ks.cfg, here is an example of kickstart that I use currently with rhel6.

```
# interactive install from CD-ROM/DVD
interactive
install
cdrom

key --skip
lang en_US.UTF-8
# keyboard us

#
clearpart --all --initlabel
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size=100
part pv.100000 --size=1 --grow
volgroup vg00 --pesize=32768 pv.100000
logvol / --fstype ext4 --name=lvroot --vgname=vg00 --size=15360
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=lvswap --vgname=vg00 --size=2048
logvol /var --fstype ext4 --name=lvvar --vgname=vg00 --size 5120

timezone Europe/Paris
firewall --disabled
authconfig --useshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing

#skipx

# pre-set list of packages/groups to install 
%packages
@core
@server-policy
acpid
device-mapper-multipath
dmidecode
# ... and so on the list of packages/groups I pre-customize (and with - those I don't want)
vsftpd
wget
xfsprogs
-autoconf
-automake
-bc
# ... and so on
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# postinstall, execution avec chroot dans le systeme installé.
%post --interpreter=/bin/sh --log=/root/post_install.log
echo -e "================================================================="
echo -e "       Starting kickStart post install script "

# do some extra stuff here , like mounting cd-rom copying add-ons specific for my product
```

Comment: Yes I see, but you uses two different media : one for booting installer, and one for rpms ?